# Is there a way to store values during runtime that stays past the termination of the program?(without using other files)

Tags: c++, memory

I'm creating an autonomous for a robot and thought it would make things way less of a pain if it memorized a controllers input for 15 seconds (the entire autonomous period) and it stored it in the program, so the next run it could execute the new information, the problem is, the program is trash and can't create any other file than the starting header and cpp file. The software I'm using is called vex coding studio. In summary, I want to find some any kind of method that can store memory for the next time the program runs.

Comment: "the program is trash and can't create any other file than the starting header and cpp file" can you expand a bit on this? I dont get your motivation for not storing in a file. It reads a bit like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: a Vex Coding Studio file (.vex) is created with a cpp and header file, and does not allow for any other file to be created (including more cpp and .h files).

Comment: I picked specifically that sentence because there must be a misunderstanding somewhere. Once you have the executable, there is no header or cpp file anymore, so having only a single header and a single source in a project is no reason to not create additional files during runtime

Comment: how would I create a file during runtime and would that file be removed when the program ends?

Comment: `#include <fstream>` holds all the built in c++ tools to read/write to files. If you create a separate file and write to it during program execution that files stays after the program has finished.

Comment: if that is your question, then make that your question ;) (but I strongly suggest you to search for "C++ create file" first and write some code, because "how to create a file?" without a [mcve] will probably get closed fast here)

Comment: I think that will work then, Thank you!

Comment: I guess your problem is very specific to vex.
Maybe the vexforum is a good reference? https://www.vexforum.com/index.php/35751-sd-card-help *Sorry, my reputation is not high enough to comment.*